# Select Query not working in Access

Tags: c#, ms-access-2013

Below given query causes the error

> OLEDbException, IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)

but it's working fine with SQL just not with Access

```
"select InvoiceNo from Sales where InvoiceNo LIKE 'B%' and cast(right(InvoiceNo, len(InvoiceNo) - 1) as int) > "+Inv_Number+""
```

`InvoiceNo` contais a letter and a number, e.g. `B1`

`Inv_Number` represent the number part

Comment: Cast does not exist in MS Access. Use Mid, Instr, Left, Right according to what suits. See also Cstr, Clng, Cint etc.

Comment: Removing `as int` and replacing `cast` with `Cint` worked perfectly thankyou  @Fionnuala